# How to get only YYYY-MM-DD output from git-log?

Tags: git

I want `git log` to show only the the date output and in the `YYYY-MM-DD` format. How do I do this?

I know about `--date=short`, but I'm not sure how to use it in `--pretty=format`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you are looking for is `%ad`.

So you can try: `git log --date=short --pretty=format:'%ad'`

If you want to see the commit message aswell try `%ad %s`.

More options in Pretty Formats section: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Regards